# 8 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: grpc: received message larger than max (120126016 vs. 104857600)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain, ibp-vscode-extension

I am using IBM Blockchain VSCode extension for testing hyperlerdger fabric node js chaincode. But I faced an issue when I tried to install a chaincode on a peer.

**Error**

```
Failed to install on peer Org1Peer1 with reason: 8 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: grpc: received message larger than max (120126016 vs. 104857600)
```

What does it mean? Can anyone guide me?

Comment: Sounds like you have created a massive chaincode package, you've probably included all sorts of stuff that's not required, eg node_modules, previous chaincode packages, .git directories etc.

Comment: @david_k Thank you for your response. I am a bit confused here. Like I am installing chaincode using IBM vs code And I just open a particular folder which was generated by default. SO how can I check this all packages?

Comment: You can view the contents of a chaincode package by going to the smart contracts panel right clicking the entry you tried to install and selecting view package information.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum payload size for a Fabric transaction is 100MB (including metadata, etc).  Your chaincode package seems to be extraordinarily large.

Comment: Thank you, How can I check the size of my fabric transaction or package?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a huge chaincode (check the whole chaincode folder size). In one case I mistakenly copied fabric bin inside the chaincode folder and got that error.